# Display image in Spring MVC

Tags: java, image, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

What is the proper way , using MultiActionController?
I got in my Restaurant class:

```
private byte[] logo;
```

In my database I got table BLOB image. By using hibernate, it saves to my database properly by:

```
<tr>
<td>Logo :</td>
<td>< input type="file" name="logo" /></td>
</tr>
```

But i dont know how to shows this image on another site. Maybe:

```
< img src="<%=("restaurant.logo")%>" alt="Upload Image" />
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like [this](http://www.programcreek.com/downloads/convert-image-to-byte.txt), create a new field in your Restaurant and have the byte[] converted to Image and use that field.

Comment: A "Spring MVC + Hibernate + Maven" fully working example: https://sites.google.com/site/adrienitnotes/java/web-apps---spring-mvc-hibernate/spring-form-image-upload-display-from-database-hibernate-simple-mapping

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you need a controller getting your picture from database and returning it as a stream to web browser.

You can for example map controller method with request:
/restaurant/logo/{id}

Then you should just type

```
<img src="<c:url value='/restaurant/logo/${restaurant.id}' />" alt="Upload Image" />
```

I you add more of code, I'll be able to give you more hints.

Answer (score 0):

Please do have a look [here](http://anirbanchowdhury.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/mybatis-upload-retrieve-download-file-or-image)!

This is more generic and points at all types of files upload and download.